# Searching Django database including ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django

I am quite new Django but have read into select_related and prefetch_related. However, I am unable to build a search function that can cover both the OneToMany relations and ManyToMany.

My Model:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag


class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    startdate = models.DateTimeField()
    stopdate = models.DateTimeField()
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    classroom = JSONField(default=json.loads("{}"), blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[ {0} ] {1}-{2}".format(self.id, self.title, self.description)

    def startdate_custom(self):
        return self.startdate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

In my view, I have a class where I want to be able to query (using a search function) over all the columns/tables (title, description, teacher, tags, classroom) in the database.
Examples below are simpified:

I can build queries on the main table:

```py
search = 'Api'
qs = self.model.objects.select_related('teacher').prefetch_related('tags')
qs = qs.filter(description__icontains=search)
```

This approach works for title, description, teacher... but not for my ManyToManyField

I can however I cannot extend that filter to the tags

```py
search = 'Api'
qs = self.model.objects.select_related('teacher').prefetch_related('tags')
qs = qs.filter(tag__icontains=search) <-- does not work
```

It seems however, I can filter out tags by iterating over tags :

```py
tags_qs = self.model.objects.all().prefetch_related('tags')
tags_list = [list(course.tags.filter(tag__icontains='API')) for course in tags_qs]
```

But this seems to yield a list of tags, whereas I need a collection of all Courses where the search term is found in either title, description, teacher OR tags.

Do I need to do 2 separate queries to the model and join them somehow (how?), or am I missing something about how to query ManyToMany Relationships?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Django how to get to the field that contains the content you want to search. In this case, the source field is `tags` and the field on the target model is called `tag`, and you join with the double-underscore syntax. So:

```
qs = qs.filter(tags__tag__icontains=search)
```